# 18.04 freezing after install

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, mouse, freeze

I was able to get 18.04 installed and working. The problem is now it freezes after some non-specific time or thing i do. Machine is ASUS Fd503VX with GTX1050. I have not installed the Nvidia drivers yet (usually does not go well). Do i need to do this, is this causing the issue? I did install the synaptic mouse driver (seems to be better). When it freezes terminal still works but cannot move the mouse (this is why i installed Synaptic).

If i do need the Nvidia drivers is the a recommended post to do this, as i when i search there are many methods. My recommended is Nvidia-drivers-390. not sure if prime or bumblbee are still needed. Last laptop i jsut gave up on Nvidia.

Comment: i tried the autoinstall, everything seemed to go well but i still get screen freeze. other thoughts?